# Does a portable secondary laptop LCD monitor exist?

Tags: laptop, display, multiple-monitors

I'm looking to buy a portable secondary LCD monitor for my MacBook Pro. Does anything like that exist?

I found [some laptops](http://ctovision.com/2009/08/finally-a-real-dual-monitor-laptop/) that provide a dual 15'' monitor solution (but it's already baked into the hardware). Also some [ideas were posted](http://www.ideastorm.com/ideaView?id=087700000000AGDAA2) about creating this type of setup back in 2007.

I'm looking for something that is as thin as a laptop LCD (with maybe a bulky power supply that I could easily daisy chain or plug into a power strip along with my laptop).

How difficult would it be to buy a 17'' laptop screen and hook up a DVI connector and power supply, and build a simple monitor stand for it?

I've gotten to used to a dual-monitor setup at work and at home with my laptop that having to use my laptop in single-screen mode makes me feel crippled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Samsung's Lapfit LD220G and LD190N are secondary LCD displays for notebook PCs. The Lapfit displays allows laptop users to get a dual display easily.

[image]

[image]

The Lapfit LD190N connects using the tradition VGA cable while the LD220G gets both VGA and UbiSync USB for video input. The latter serves also as a USB hub. The 22-inch LD220G features 1920×1080 pixels full HD resolution while the 19-inch LD190N has 1360×768. They both have 250 cd/m<sup>2</sup> brightness, 20,000:1 dynamic contrast, and 5 ms response time.

The Samsung Lapfit LD220G and LD190N are priced at US$249.99 and US$149.99 respectively.

Nanovision offers some smaller (7") USB displays:

[image]

[image]

Comment: LD220G looks like just what I'm looking for (hopefully I can find a case for it to put in my laptop bag).

Answer (score 1):

http://www.mmt2.com is another option; a portable 15.4" monitor with DisplayLink and USB connectivity.